# Can I install a customized image of ubuntu with wubi?

Tags: wubi

I have a customized image of ubuntu which I want to install with wubi, there are any procedure to install it without a standard installation or any VM?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Wubi looks for an ISO image of an installation CD in the same directory as the executable wubi.exe. Therefore, most likely you can, but I'd first try it out.